# Woocommerce - Link product SKU to image

Tags: wordpress, image, csv, woocommerce

I have uploaded via csv more than 1000 products and added relative images. In the csv file i have linked an image for each product with the same name of the product SKU + `.jpg` (example SKU: `MA3456` - image: `MA3456.jpg`).

Now I have 2 problems:

1. The images uploaded don't actually always match the SKU, for example many of them are as following: SKU= `MA1234` - image name= `MA1234_6.jpg` or `MA1234_6B.jpg` .This way the product won't obviously find the relative image...
   Maybe there is a way to tell the product to match the SKU plus anything else ('MA1234**')? or just any image that contains the sku number 'MA1234' ?
2. Many products have more than one image associated to it with changes in the filename after an underscore, for example: SKU= `MA1234` - image name= `MA1234_6.jpg` / `MA1234_6B.jpg` / `MA1234_7.jpg` / `MA1234_7B.jpg` etc.

How can I solve these problems ?

Most important is the first, I need to have at least one image attached to each product.

Comment: Did you try All Import Pro [link](http://www.wpallimport.com/)- plugin for importing product? You can set image names to SKU on them.